# Assign a single ID from multiple observations

Tags: r

I have got a survey dataset in which respondents appear several times. The respondents are identified by an ID. Additional to that there is a second variable (IDPREV) which gives the ID under which the respondent was previously identified (the ID which was assigned to the respondent at the last interview). I would like to create a unique ID for each respondent which stays the same each time the respondent is interviewed. The respondent can appear several times in the dataset. Any suggestions & ideas are appreciated! Thank you!

The structure looks something like that. Unfortunately it is just not that well organized and the respondents can appear several times:

```
structure(c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
1, 2, 3, 4, 5), .Dim = c(10L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("ID", 
"IDPREV")))
```

Comment: hello, a simple `dput(<your data>)` would be helpful.  What does your data look like right now?  (What is the structure? Do you have it in R or elsewhere, etc)

Comment: You need to explain why the first mentioned ID is not sufficient. If these are data in an R data-object you need to provide output from: `dput(head(object))`. If not, then this is really not a programming question, is it?

Comment: the ID is not sufficient because it is sequential. and after three years i have got a second id (IDPREV) which refers to the last observation of the respondent; the data is stored as a dataset. i cannot provide you with original data because the dataset is too long, i would have to stratify it, and it is confidential.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this should converge quickly:

```
x      <- ifelse(is.na(df$IDPREV), df$ID, df$IDPREV)
update <- function(x) x[match(x, df$ID)]
y      <- update(x)

while(!identical(y, x)) {
  x <- y
  y <- update(x)
}

df$FINAL_ID <- x
```

---

Tested with:

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12), 
                     IDPREV = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10, 11)),
                .Names = c("ID", "IDPREV"),
                row.names = c(NA, 12L), class = "data.frame")
```

The final output is:

```
#    ID IDPREV FINAL_ID
# 1   1     NA        1
# 2   2     NA        2
# 3   3     NA        3
# 4   4     NA        4
# 5   5     NA        5
# 6   6      1        1
# 7   7      2        2
# 8   8      3        3
# 9   9      4        4
# 10 10      5        5
# 11 11     10        5
# 12 12     11        5
```

Comment: I've had a go at replicating your answer using `igraph`. Let me know if I'm missing something.

Answer (score 1):

You can merge a data-object to itself:

```
 dat <- structure(c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
 1, 2, 3, 4, 5), .Dim = c(10L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("ID", 
 "IDPREV")))
 dat2 <- merge(dat, dat, by.x=1, by.y=2)
Warning message:
In merge.data.frame(as.data.frame(x), as.data.frame(y), ...) :
  column name ‘ID’ is duplicated in the result

 dat2
#-----------------
  ID IDPREV ID
1  1     NA  6
2  2     NA  7
3  3     NA  8
4  4     NA  9
5  5     NA 10
```

You would probably want to create a more informative column name for the second "ID" variable.

```
 names(dat)[3] <- "Second.ID"
```

Answer (score 1):

This could also be conceptualised as a graph object and allow the use of the `igraph` package. E.g., using @flodel's data from his answer.

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12), 
                     IDPREV = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10, 11)),
                .Names = c("ID", "IDPREV"),
                row.names = c(NA, 12L), class = "data.frame")

require(igraph)    
# get rid of the effect of the NAs by matching these cases 
# back to themselves; make a graph; then extract the clusters
df$IDPREV[is.na(df$IDPREV)] <- df$ID[is.na(df$IDPREV)]
g.el <- graph.data.frame(df)
df$FINAL_ID_LM <- clusters(g.el)$membership
```

Gives the same result as @flodel's answer:

```
> df
   ID IDPREV FINAL_ID_LM FINAL_ID_FL
1   1      1           1           1
2   2      2           2           2
3   3      3           3           3
4   4      4           4           4
5   5      5           5           5
6   6      1           1           1
7   7      2           2           2
8   8      3           3           3
9   9      4           4           4
10 10      5           5           5
11 11     10           5           5
12 12     11           5           5
```